# What happens to threads in the Entry set of a monitor when the lock is released?

Tags: java, multithreading

As we know, in Java, there is a monitor associated with any object.
When a monitor is held by a thread, any other threads that attempt to acquire the monitor will be blocked and placed in the Entry Set of the monitor. 
What happens to the threads waiting in the Entry Set when the monitor was released?

So far as I know, if the thread that released the monitor invoked Object.notify/notifyAll, then one of the threads or all threads in the Wait Set of the monitor was/were moved to the Entry Set.
For threads in the Entry Set, will all of them be resumed, namely with their state be changed from BLOCKED TO RUNNABLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will all of them be resumed

If all threads will be resumed, then either synchronization won't work (because they all will acquire the lock) or all the threads will re-enter the entry-set, and the lucky one will acquire the lock. While the first approach is incorrect, the second one obviously has performance issues.

It should be obvious that random (unless lock is fair) thread from the entry set acquires the lock and resumes its workflow.

You may be interested in the next [article](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/multithreading-difference-between-lock-and-monitor/) - pay attention to the last [diagram](http://howtodoinjava.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/java-monitor.gif).

Comment: The newly arrived thread always compete only with the ones in the entry-set. However while a thread owns a monitor it may satisfy some conditions, thus moving some threads from the wait-set to the entry-set. Is it what you were asking for?

Comment: Thanks @user3707125 ! Of course, only one thread will be the next owner of the monitor being released, so my question focuses on how this happen. By randomly choosing a thread and giving it a chance to acquire the monitor or resuming all threads and letting those thread `compete` for the monitor?

Comment: Why would anyone resume all the threads? I mentioned this in my answer: "or all the threads will re-enter the entry-set" & "the second one obviously has performance issues". What if 100 threads are waiting? It will take a lot of context-switching to decide who is the winner, with no practical benefit.

Comment: _the newly arrived thread always compete only with the ones in the entry-set_
I understand this, this is why we call the intrinsic lock a non-fair lock. 
I also understand that the result of _compete_ is that only will thread will be the winner, but my focus is not on the outcome of _compete_, it is the _compete_ itself, namely exact meaning of _compete_ or how _compete_ is implemented.
If the _compete_ is implemented in a vm-specific way, could someone give some concrete example?

Comment: @user2351818, it is totally VM-specific. However I have no idea how it is implemented in different VMs, and I am very unsure that anyone may need these details for any practical reason. Especially when we have fair locks through ReentrantLock.

Comment: [this](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html) articles says that _To a great extent, the manner in which a Java virtual machine implementation **selects the next thread** from the wait or entry sets is a decision of individual implementation designers_

Comment: Except that it _isn't_ decided by most JVM designers.  Most JVMs use _native threads_ which means that the JVM "implements" lock and unlock and wait and notify by calling the operating system, and letting the operating system do the work.